# how to get child element in a click event typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

Please how do to get child element in a click event typescript
this is the code  currently have

```
    import { MouseEvent } from "react";
    const clicked = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>)=>{
      console.log(e.target)
      console.log(e.target.firstElementChild) // not working
    
    }
    
    const QuizQuestionContainer =()=>{
      return(
        <form>
                <div onClick={clicked}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    value={option1}
                    name="option"
                    onChange={checkOption}
                    checked={checked === option1}
                  />
                  <label>{option1}</label>
                </div>
                </form>
      )
    }
    export default QuizQuestionContainer;
```

Please help me out...

Comment: What does it mean `not working`?

Comment: this is the error I am getting
Property 'firstElementChild' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: Are you sure that this code compiles? You are missing `=>`

Comment: mistake from writing the post sorry

Comment: What is `e.target` in the console?

Comment: You want to use `e.currentTarget`. The `e.target` type can't be known (automatically) at compile time.